# Using SHA512 to store login passwords instead of MD5

Tags: php, security, password-storage

I have been reading a lot online that MD5 is not very secure, i have decided to switch my site over to use SHA512, i have never done this before so really i am just asking you to check to see if i have done it correctly, or is there an alternative more secure hash method which i can use to store the password ?

$upass is the users password which i need to hash.

Here was my origional PHP with MD5 :

```
 $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
 $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
```

Here is my new PHP using SHA :

```
 $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
 $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sname']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

 $upass = hash('SHA512', $upass);
```

Here is also the hashed string for the word "password" just to make sure the hashing is working.

SHA512 :

b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e

MD5 :

5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

Thanks for any help / advice in advance.

Comment: While you are fixing/updating the code to use "good, modern practices", also use placeholders / parameterized queries and mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Neither MD5 nor SHA512 are encryption ciphers but cryptographic hash functions. That’s a huge difference: A hash function has no reverse operation while an encryption has (i. e., the decryption).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way would be to use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` for the algorithm. That way, you will have a good algorithm (bcrypt, if you have PHP 5.5), which may be automatically upgraded to a better one in future versions of PHP, withouth the need to change your code. The passwords are also hashed with a salt.

Comment: That sound great, I'm not familiar with password_hash, please would you edit my code to accommodate for it please ?

Comment: In your code it's almost a drop-in replacement for `hash`. Apart from hashing, you also need checking, of course. That is done using [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). The documentation pages contain examples to get you started.

Comment: Thats great thank you, I've just added that, is there a way to change the cost ?

Comment: Yes. The third parameter is an array of options, which can contain a cost.

Comment: @BradleyCouisns The cost *should* cost CPU time and should not be set to lower than the default. The cost is one reason why bcrypt - and *unlike SHA*, of any length - is suitable for a password hash.